# How do I display list of items horizontally on a list View, using WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I tried replacing the StackPanel inside with a Wrap Panel, Nothing Worked. Even tried Wrapping everything with a wrap-panel, still no difference.

This is my code.

```
  <ListView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="MyListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Games}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <ContentControl >
                                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                                            <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.OpenGameCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Id}" />
                                        </i:EventTrigger>
                                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <Image MaxHeight="150" IsEnabled="False" Source="{Binding Image}"/>
                                        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </ContentControl>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

This is the output

[OUTPUP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Iizd.png)

Comment: The stack panel with the image and textblock just need it's orientation set to horizontal.

Comment: ...And the WrapPanel didn't work for you because your item template has no fixed width. That way, each item in the wrap panel occupies 1 entire row. So it looks like it's horizontal stack. You should probably set width somewhere in the hierarchy.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, it's not working as it should. Check the output on the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do set `ListView.ItemsPanel` to `StackPanel` with `Orientation="Horizontal"`

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="MyListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Games}">

    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ContentControl >
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                            <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.OpenGameCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Id}" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image MaxHeight="150" IsEnabled="False" Source="{Binding Image}"/>
                        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </ContentControl>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: I tried that, it says markup invalid. Note that the panel have two componets, the image and text under the image, and everything repeat vertically, more images and text, instead of horizontally, as I posted on the question's output picture above

Comment: You can leave your `ListView.ItemTemplate`, but add the code for `ListView.ItemsPanel` unmodified as it stays in the answer.

Comment: Your answer is similar to most references on the internet, but it's just not working for me, I guess I am just not understanding something

Comment: I have modified an answer.

Comment: You are God-sent. Thank you buddy. All the best.
It worked.

Comment: You are welcome.